# ApplicationInsights breaks default Spring Boot configuration for static content

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, azure-application-insights

I have a Spring Boot Rest Web Service. I've also added static content with swagger-ui to the src/main/resources/static.swagger-ui so I can access my documentation.

By default SimpleUrlHandlerMapping is mapping my request to the static content automatically during startup.

```
...
2017-09-07 15:41:21.144  INFO 6912 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-09-07 15:41:21.144  INFO 6912 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-09-07 15:41:21.212  INFO 6912 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
...
```

I added reference to the Application Insights in my gradle file

```
... part of my gradle file
// Application Insight related jar - required for telemetrics and loggers
compile("com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-web:${aiWeb}")
compile("com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-logging-logback:${aiLogback}")
...
```

This is somehow breaking SimpleUrlHandlerMapping as mapping to the static content doesn't work any more.

Any idea how to fix it? I could probably add mapper manually...

My stack:

- springBootVersion=1.5.3.RELEASE
- springSecurityVersion=4.2.1.RELEASE
- aiWeb=1.0.9 aiLogback=1.0.6

Answer (score 1):

After the whole day of debugging I think I found a root cause (workaround for sure)

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration) of Spring Boot it automaticly configure Spring MVC. That involves configuration of static content.

If we take look at the **applicationinsights.web** pacakge there is a class called InterceptorRegistry

```
package com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.spring.internal;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.spring.RequestNameHandlerInterceptorAdapter;

/**
 * This class registers the RequestNameHandlerInterceptorAdapter to the interceptors registry.
 * The registration enables the interceptor to extract the http request's controller and action names.
 */
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class InterceptorRegistry extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new RequestNameHandlerInterceptorAdapter());
    }
}
```

And this is what documentation says:

> If you want to keep Spring Boot MVC features, and you just want to add
>   additional MVC configuration (interceptors, formatters, view
>   controllers etc.) you can add your own @Configuration class of type
>   WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, but **without** @EnableWebMvc

So it seems that there is a bug in the package as a class contains **@EnableWebMvc** annotation that breaks auto configuration feature.

I have not recompiled that library without this annotation so I'm not 100% sure if removing this tag would fix this issue. What I did is is adding mapping manually.

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/swagger-ui/");
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }
}
```